# Difference between selector and SEL and method call [ ]?

Tags: ios

I am so confused that whenever we pass an object to selector, it sends the object to target where target tells the where this object is implemented? but when i call like this [self methodname] or [anotherClassObject methodname]. so what is the basic difference between selector calling and in square method calling? Also tells the What is SEL?

Comment: I believe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608476/whats-the-difference-between-a-method-and-a-selector) has already answered your question.

Comment: @orkster, what do you mean?

Comment: I added a hyperlink to the words "this post", but looking at it now, the color difference is not super-obvious. This is the post I was referring to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608476/whats-the-difference-between-a-method-and-a-selector